# Should I get a credit card?

Tags: credit-card

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do I even need credit cards?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/4107/do-i-even-need-credit-cards)

I am 26, I have never had a credit card because I have seen them ruin peoples credit.

I try my best to not live beyond my means, and not having a credit card is one of the ways I do that. I save to buy those big items. If I were to get one I am afraid I would buy too much unnecessary stuff and go in debt.

I have thought about getting one though, because I hear its the best way to improve your credit if you use them wisely.

They can also be useful in emergencies I guess.

So this is kind of a multi-part question.

**Should I get a credit card?**

Being that I have never had one I am guessing I would have a very high interest rate. Plus I don't know how to use them wisely. I am not sure what is the best thing.

So if I should get one, **what would be a wise plan to make having one benefit me rather than detriment me?**

Also **is there a specific kind I should get?**